# eglibc-2.19 nptl compilation failed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, lts, glibc

I was trying to build eglibc-2.19 which I downloaded through

```
apt-get source libc6
```

I followed the INSTALL instructions but got this error when it ran into nptl,

```
gcc sem_init.c -c -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline -fno-stack-protector -O2 -Wall -Winline -Wwrite-strings -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -g -Wstrict-prototypes      -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE   -I../include -I/home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/glibc-build/nptl  -I/home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/glibc-build  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../nptl/sysdeps/pthread  -I../libpthread/sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/x86_64  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix  -I../ports/sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../libpthread/sysdeps/posix  -I../nptl/sysdeps/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch  -I../nptl/sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I../libpthread/include -I../libpthread  -I../nptl  -I../ports  -I.. -I../libio -I.  -I../libpthread/include  -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include ../include/libc-symbols.h   -DNOT_IN_libc=1 -DIS_IN_libpthread=1 -DIN_LIB=libpthread    -o /home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/glibc-build/nptl/sem_init.o -MD -MP -MF /home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/glibc-build/nptl/sem_init.o.dt -MT /home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/glibc-build/nptl/sem_init.o
In file included from sem_init.c:20:0:
../libpthread/include/semaphore.h:28:0: warning: "SEM_FAILED" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define SEM_FAILED ((void *) 0)
 ^
In file included from ../libpthread/include/semaphore.h:26:0,
                 from sem_init.c:20:
../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/bits/semaphore.h:33:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define SEM_FAILED      ((sem_t *) 0)
 ^
In file included from sem_init.c:20:0:
../libpthread/include/semaphore.h:30:28: error: conflicting types for ‘sem_t’
 typedef struct __semaphore sem_t;
                            ^
In file included from ../libpthread/include/semaphore.h:26:0,
                 from sem_init.c:20:
../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/bits/semaphore.h:40:3: note: previous declaration of ‘sem_t’ was here
 } sem_t;
   ^
make[2]: *** [/home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/glibc-build/nptl/sem_init.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/eglibc-2.19/nptl'
make[1]: *** [nptl/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/eglibc-2.19'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I also tried on another 14.04 LTS of mine, also got the same error.

```
uname -a
Linux gpanda-ibmt420 3.13.0-65-generic #105-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 21 18:50:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Could somebody please tell me how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run `./configure` in the source folder and add the output to your question.