# eglibc-2.19 nptl build failure on 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: 14.04, glibc

`vagrant@precise64:~/eglibc-2.19/build$ ../configure --prefix=/tmp/eglibc-2.19`

produces:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for sysdeps preconfigure fragments... powerpc x86_64 checking whether gcc compiles in -mx32 mode by default... no

configure: running configure fragment for add-on fbtl
configure: running configure fragment for add-on libidn
configure: running configure fragment for add-on libpthread
configure: running configure fragment for add-on nptl
checking add-on ports for preconfigure fragments... aarch64 alpha am33 arm hppa ia64 m68k microblaze mips tile
checking for assembler and linker STT_GNU_IFUNC support... yes
checking whether .text pseudo-op must be used... yes
checking sysdep dirs... sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64/nptl sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64 nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64 nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64 nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux nptl/sysdeps/pthread libpthread/sysdeps/pthread sysdeps/pthread ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux sysdeps/gnu sysdeps/unix/inet nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv sysdeps/unix/sysv sysdeps/unix/x86_64 nptl/sysdeps/unix ports/sysdeps/unix sysdeps/unix sysdeps/posix libpthread/sysdeps/posix nptl/sysdeps/x86_64/64 sysdeps/x86_64/64 sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch sysdeps/x86_64/fpu sysdeps/x86/fpu sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch nptl/sysdeps/x86_64 sysdeps/x86_64 sysdeps/x86 sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 sysdeps/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754 sysdeps/generic
configure: WARNING: add-on debian contributed no sysdeps directories
configure: WARNING: add-on ports contributed no useful sysdeps directories
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether as is GNU as... yes
checking whether ld is GNU ld... yes
checking for as... as
checking version of as... 2.24, ok
checking for ld... ld
checking version of ld... 2.24, ok
checking for gcc... gcc
checking version of gcc... 4.8.4, ok
checking for gnumake... no
checking for gmake... no
checking for make... make
checking version of make... 3.81, ok
checking for gnumsgfmt... no
checking for gmsgfmt... no
checking for msgfmt... no
checking for makeinfo... no
checking for sed... sed
checking version of sed... 4.2.2, ok
checking for gawk... gawk
checking version of gawk... 4.0.1, ok
checking for nm... nm
configure: WARNING:
*** These auxiliary programs are missing or incompatible versions: msgfmt makeinfo
*** some features will be disabled.
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
checking LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable... ok
checking whether GCC supports -static-libgcc... -static-libgcc
checking for bash... /bin/bash
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for install-info... /usr/bin/install-info
checking for bison... no
checking for libc-friendly stddef.h... yes
checking whether we need to use -P to assemble .S files... no
checking for .set assembler directive... yes
checking for assembler gnu_unique_object symbol type... yes
checking for .previous assembler directive... yes
checking for .protected and .hidden assembler directive... yes
checking whether __attribute__((visibility())) is supported... yes
checking for broken __attribute__((visibility()))... no
checking for broken __attribute__((alias()))... no
checking whether to put _rtld_local into .sdata section... no
checking for .preinit_array/.init_array/.fini_array support... yes
checking whether to use .ctors/.dtors header and trailer... no
checking for libunwind-support in compiler... no
checking for linker that supports -z nodelete... yes
checking for linker that supports -z nodlopen... yes
checking for linker that supports -z initfirst... yes
checking for -z relro option... yes
checking for -Bgroup option... yes
checking whether --noexecstack is desirable for .S files... yes
checking for -z combreloc... yes
checking for linker that supports -z execstack... yes
checking for -fpie... yes
checking for --hash-style option... yes
checking for sufficient default -shared layout... no
checking linker output format... elf64-x86-64
checking for -fno-toplevel-reorder -fno-section-anchors... yes
checking for -fstack-protector... yes
checking for -fgnu89-inline... yes
checking whether cc puts quotes around section names... no
checking for assembler .weak directive... yes
checking whether CFI directives are supported... yes
checking for ld --no-whole-archive... yes
checking for gcc -fexceptions... yes
checking for __builtin_memset... yes
checking for redirection of built-in functions... yes
checking for __thread... yes
checking for tls_model attribute... yes
checking for compiler option to disable generation of FMA instructions... -ffp-contract=off
checking if gcc accepts -fno-tree-loop-distribute-patterns with __attribute__ ((__optimize__))... yes
checking for libgd... no
checking for is_selinux_enabled in -lselinux... no
checking size of long double... 16
checking for _FORTIFY_SOURCE predefine... yes
checking whether gcc implicitly enables -fstack-protector... yes
running configure fragment for nptl/sysdeps/pthread
checking for forced unwind support... yes
checking for C cleanup handling... yes
running configure fragment for sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking installed Linux kernel header files... 2.6.19 or later
checking for kernel header at least 2.6.16... ok
checking for linux/fanotify.h... yes
checking for symlinks in /tmp/eglibc-2.19/include... ok
running configure fragment for sysdeps/gnu
running configure fragment for nptl/sysdeps/x86_64
checking for .cfi_personality and .cfi_lsda pseudo-ops... yes
running configure fragment for sysdeps/x86_64
checking for cpuid.h... yes
checking for SSE4 support... yes
checking for AVX support... yes
checking for AVX encoding of SSE instructions... yes
checking for FMA4 support... yes
checking for -mno-vzeroupper support... yes
checking for old glibc 2.0.x headers... no
checking whether -fPIC is default... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.make
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing default commands
```

and a subsequent 'make' produces:

```
vagrant@precise64:~/eglibc-2.19/build$ make
...
...
...
gcc sem_init.c -c -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline -fno-stack-protector -O2 -Wall -Winline -Wwrite-strings -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -g -Wstrict-prototypes      -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE   -I../include -I/home/vagrant/eglibc-2.19/build/nptl  -I/home/vagrant/eglibc-2.19/build  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../nptl/sysdeps/pthread  -I../libpthread/sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/x86_64  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix  -I../ports/sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../libpthread/sysdeps/posix  -I../nptl/sysdeps/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch  -I../nptl/sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I../debian  -I../libpthread/include -I../libpthread  -I../nptl  -I../ports  -I.. -I../libio -I.  -I../libpthread/include  -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include ../include/libc-symbols.h   -DNOT_IN_libc=1 -DIS_IN_libpthread=1 -DIN_LIB=libpthread    -o /home/vagrant/eglibc-2.19/build/nptl/sem_init.o -MD -MP -MF /home/vagrant/eglibc-2.19/build/nptl/sem_init.o.dt -MT /home/vagrant/eglibc-2.19/build/nptl/sem_init.o
In file included from sem_init.c:20:0:
../libpthread/include/semaphore.h:28:0: warning: "SEM_FAILED" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define SEM_FAILED ((void *) 0)
 ^
In file included from ../libpthread/include/semaphore.h:26:0,
                 from sem_init.c:20:
../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/bits/semaphore.h:33:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define SEM_FAILED      ((sem_t *) 0)
 ^
In file included from sem_init.c:20:0:
../libpthread/include/semaphore.h:30:28: error: conflicting types for 'sem_t'
 typedef struct __semaphore sem_t;
                            ^
In file included from ../libpthread/include/semaphore.h:26:0,
                 from sem_init.c:20:
../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/bits/semaphore.h:40:3: note: previous declaration of 'sem_t' was here
 } sem_t;
   ^
make[2]: *** [/home/vagrant/eglibc-2.19/build/nptl/sem_init.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/eglibc-2.19/nptl'
make[1]: *** [nptl/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/eglibc-2.19'
make: *** [all] Error 2
vagrant@precise64:~/eglibc-2.19/build$
```

Kernel version:

```
vagrant@precise64:~/eglibc-2.19/build$ uname -a
Linux precise64 3.13.0-74-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:52:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
vagrant@precise64:~/eglibc-2.19/build$
```

Also attempted on kernel version:

```
vagrant@precise64:~/eglibc-2.19/build$ uname -a
Linux precise64 4.2.0-23-generic #28~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 31 13:40:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
vagrant@precise64:~/eglibc-2.19/build$
```

Comment: Your hostname is `precise64`. Are you sure you're using 14.04?

Comment: Hi, yes I recently upgraded to 14.04. I initially installed the vm as 12.04.

Comment: Is there really nobody that can help? There's another identical question here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/681363/eglibc-2-19-nptl-compilation-failed-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) so this may not be isolated.